# aligning divs using float and z-index

Tags: html, css

I can't believe I can't get this working!

This is basically the look I'm going for but can't get it like this at all!

```
+------------------------------------------+
|   Div 1                                  |
|             +-------------+              |
|             | Div 2       |              |
+-------------|             |--------------+
+-------------|             |--------------+
|  Div 3      |             |   Div 4      |
|             +-------------+              |
|               |        +-----------------+
|               |+-------------------------+
|               || Div 5                   |
|               ||                         |
|               ||                         |
+---------------++-------------------------+
```

I have tried placing the divs in every different order possible.

I have the container for the whole page set as `position: relative`

```
#div1 {
    width: 950px;
}
#div2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: -100px auto 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 88;
 }
#div3 {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 0;
}
#div4 {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    z-index: 0;
}
#div5 {
    width: 600px;
    float: right;
    clear: right;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

I got divs 1,2,3 and 4 to work fine. But when I add div 5 it messes everything up. Div 2 seems to be an issue, Div 5 seems to want to align itself to that.

If you could please help, it would save me another bump on my forehead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing two things, in order to absolutely position elements `position:relative` , they must be included inside a position relative wrapper. also it seems that since the element don't have a defined hight they collapse.

Please see attached fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/4TCJ9/

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="align">    
 <div id="div3"></div>
 <div id="div4"></div>
 <div id="div5"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
position:relative;
}

div {
border:1px solid black;
background: yellow;

}

#div1 {
width: 950px;
height:200px;
}
#div2 {
position: absolute;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
left: 40%;
top: 100px;
z-index: 88;
  }
#align{
width:950px;
float:left;
position:relative;
height:auto;

}
#div3 {
float: left;
width: 200px;
z-index: 0;
height:400px;
}
#div4 {
width: 745px;
text-align: center;
float: left;
z-index: 0;
height:200px;
}
#div5 {
width: 745px;
float: left;
clear: right;
z-index: 1;
height:200px;
}
```

Change the sizes depends on your need.